# adding environment variables does not work for JFLEX windows 10

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, jflex

So, I watched a few YouTube videos and read a few Stack overflow answers, and here is what I've done so far for paths in the environment variables:
JAVA_HOME:

```
C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\java6\nt64\jre\bin\java.exe
```

JFLEX_HOME:

```
C:\jflex-1.9.1
```

path:

```
C:\jflex-1.9.1\bin
```

I'm using the eclipse 2022-12 version, so I did not install anything while installing it.
These are the errors it gives me:

```
'JFLEX_HOME' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'JFLEX_VERSION' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please, I'd be so thankful if you'd help me.